Does God the Son have Faith?
While answering another question, a comment perplexed me and I cannot quite understand it.

"It was not Christ 'fulfilling the law' that saved, but him bearing the punishment for sin we all deserve, in our stead. So God's righteous punishment for sin was borne by Christ though he was sinless. It wasn't his Passion. It was his faith unto death."

Which Christian faiths teach that1 it was not the "fulfillment of the Law" & "Passion of Christ" that saved us, but instead Jesus' Faith? That is... God's Faith in God, saved us.
1(The bolded phrase above is my Primary Question, i.e. which denomination/faiths and with what reasoning)
To my understanding God does not have Faith.
Perhaps there is an alternative definition of "Faith" being used here that I am unaware of? (Alternative thought, that might explain my confusion)
Even the faith tag on this site says: "Faith: Belief, trust, and loyalty towards God, Jesus, and the Christian religion."
I've been unable to find anything online or in reference sources, because all "hits" when searching the term "God+Faith" give results about how humans should have faith in God. Not about how God has Faith.

Can you provide a link to the comment in question, or the answer that contains it? That context is probably helpful

@automaton Not this time no. It is on this site, and I don't want to be rude and give the user any additional attention. Otherwise, yes I definitely would.

@automaton  I made the comment in question, and add this, to clear matters up. It was the faith of Christ that not only led to what is often called "his Passion" but his faith enabled him to go right through to death on a cross. I'm not a user of the phrase "his Passion" so may have misunderstood what that is meant to entail.  But my question (link given above in this Q) deals with how God's righteousness was demonstrated at the cross.

The proper way to express this would be to ask if Jesus Christ demonstrated faith while upon this earth. The term 'God the Son' is inappropriate in this particular context.

@NigelJ Eh... Fully Human, Fully God. Eastern Orthodox doctrine. I admit the human side could have faith, but no part of the Trinity would do anything against the WIll of the Father anyways, and the definitions for faith are usually for us little mortals. So I was expecting some interesting answers. Obviously it is also very telling about the beliefs of the various users here seeing the upvotes and how certain doctrines affect this answer. It's actually a complex question if one takes the time to deeply ponder it. Your answer would be of interest as well. :)

Christ the Son, the image of the invisible God (Col 1:15), was also fully human while living.  It was first by His faith (as being fully man) that righteousness came.  It is effectively our faith in His faith (the faith He alone maintained on our behalf) that we are then justified.  We are "made the righteousness of God in Him" (2 Cor 5:21), upon having this faith alone in Him alone.  It is this imputed righteousness that justifies us before God (Rom 4:1-16), and not by our own self-righteous efforts of justification (Rom 10:3, Eph 2:8-9).  Our faith is then in Him (the result of His faith) and nothing of ourselves.
Galatians 2:16

Knowing that a man is not justified by the works of the law, but by the faith of Jesus Christ, even we have believed in Jesus Christ, that we might be justified by the faith of Christ, and not by the works of the law: for by the works of the law shall no flesh be justified.

Faith is required to please God, and it was Christ in whom God was well pleased.
Hebrews 11:6

But without faith it is impossible to please him: for he that cometh to God must believe that he is, and that he is a rewarder of them that diligently seek him.

Matthew 3:17

And lo a voice from heaven, saying, This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased.


Hey, which particular christian faith perspective is this? I appreciate the explanation too :) I'm guessing by the use of the word "Imputed" that it is a type of Protestant?

Thanks Wyrsa!  It is THE Christian faith perspective.  The word "imputed" is of scripture, not a denomination (Rom 4:1-16).

Yes, "fully human" is the key here. The human Jesus had to have faith that he himself wasn't simply delusional, and that if he refrained from sin the Father would resurrect him. Can you imagine what it must be like to live your whole life believing that you used to be an immortal god and not having doubts about your own sanity?

@RayButterworth Thanks Ray!!

@RayButterworth from the EO perspective Christ is/was/will always be 100% Human and 100% God. But I know your specific view is different. And that's what makes this site and the answers from different denominations intellectually interesting.

@RayButterworth I think the point is more about the thought of having to live your whole life to perfection for salvation that would be the unbearable burden.  That was the purpose of Christ and Him crucified...for us.  ...so we do not have to bear that burden, as we are incapable of living that righteous life for God.

@MarkVestal I wouldn't call it "THE" christian faith perspective. The concept of imputed righteousness is a protestant one. The EO church would say that righteousness is incorporated not imputed.  The EO understanding of Salvation is by grace in response to active faith that is expressed by doing more then just "confessing Jesus is Lord" but by caring for the least of Jesus' brethren (Mt. 25). God's righteousness is a gift of loving, merciful, saving grace, not a forensic tool that is wielded in the service of divine judgement. :(

@Wyrsa Yes, many do not believe our truths found in scripture :(  - 1 Cor 3:11 "For other foundation can no man lay than that is laid, which is Jesus Christ." Gal 1:6-7 "I marvel that ye are so soon removed from him that called you into the grace of Christ unto another gospel: 7 Which is not another; but there be some that trouble you, and would pervert the gospel of Christ." Rom 4:4-5 "Now to him that worketh is the reward not reckoned of grace, but of debt. 5 But to him that worketh not, but believeth on him that justifieth the ungodly, his faith is counted for righteousness."

I'll stick to what my Church teaches and has safeguarded, intellectually please accept that. But I respect and value each answer here, even if I personally or my church does not agree. :) That is what makes this SE site so interesting.

Should @Wyrsa and Mark's latest two comments be another question?  I would interpret "Now to him that worketh is the reward not reckoned of grace" as meaning that if one's works are done for the purpose of earning grace, they are useless (as opposed to doing works because it feels natural and one wants to). Are there differing denominational positions on this?

@RayButterworth I believe your interpretation is an absolute truth for the church, which is the body of Christ (Col 1:24).

In order for the Word to became flesh, he had to empty himself of the glory he had with the Father in Heaven. He had to take the form of a servant and be found in likeness of man (Philippians 2:7), confined to living on Earth. He no longer had sight of Heaven or of the Father. He had to seek communion with God in Heaven the way all humans have to - prayer based on knowledge of, and belief in, God's written word, obedience to that word, and worship of God. That is why he was circumcised on the 8th day, was found in the temple even as a boy, discussing the scriptures with great understanding, attended the synagogue and festivals in Jerusalem, and then carried out the mission he had been sent to Earth to fulfil - even unto death on a  cross.
In all of this, he was fully human - not merely appearing to be a human. He had to walk by faith, not sight, for he was no longer in heaven. He had to believe all that the scriptures foretold of him as Messiah, living to do God's will, and dying in faith that the Father would not abandon him to the grave. God the Son had faith while on Earth. Now he is back in Heaven, sharing the very throne of God, he does not exercise faith.
Those who are in Heaven do not need to have faith in God for they are in his very presence! And although even the demons believe there is but one God, they tremble at knowing what God is going to do to them. They do not have faith in God, the faith that saves. (James 2:19) But when on Earth, the God-man Jesus cried out to the Father:

"Who, in the days of his flesh, when he had offered up prayers and
supplications with strong crying and tears unto him that was able to
save him from death, and was heard in that he feared; though he were a
Son, yet learned he obedience by the things which he suffered" Hebrews
5:7-8 K.J.V.

It was his obedience unto death that showed he had faith. It wasn't "keeping the law" on our behalf that did it for us. It was the Son of God's perfect faith in God the Father that enabled him to suffer that horrific death. That may be called "Christ's Passion" - I never use that term myself. I speak of Christ's suffering unto death. And if he had not had faith in the Father to save him from that death, he would never have got through the anguish of Gethsemane as he contemplated it. Only after he had accepted it was God's will for him did an angel come and minister to him.
As for those who disagree that it was "the fulfillment of the Law", or (in other words) "that Christ fulfilled the Law on our behalf", that is a matter I could write pages about, quoting from various books and articles. Likewise with explaining the correct translation of Galatians 2:20 K.J.V, which says of Christians that, in the flesh, they "now live by the faith of the Son of God...".  Also, Galatians 2:20, ‘I am crucified with Christ: nevertheless I live; yet not I, but Christ liveth in me: and the life which I now live in the flesh I live by the faith of the Son of God, who loved me, and gave himself for me.’
Modern translations have warped this, just by abuse of one little Greek word, changing 'faith of Christ' to 'faith in Christ. But those two texts never said 'faith in Jesus Christ'. The preposition is not ἐν, but δua.  The case is genitive. This is the accepted Greek text: δικαιοσύνη δὲ θεοῦ διὰ πίστεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ  The preposition is not ἐν, but δua. The case is genitive, so it cannot read ‘in’. However, this has now branched into hermeneutics, so perhaps a fresh question could be placed there.
So, this all goes to back up my answer that, While the Son of God was on Earth, he had faith; he demonstrated that faith right up to death on a cross.

As Greek Orthodox, I do appreciate how you attended to the proper words used in the passage. :) Anne, when you said fully human towards the beginning, is that "only" human or similar to the EO where it is fully human fully God?

@Wyrsa  We both believe in the trinitarian teaching that Jesus was fully human and fully God. Those who do not believe Jesus was fully God suppose that Jesus having faith somehow 'exposes' error in the Trinity doctrine.  It does not; it is their misunderstanding of the Trinity doctrine that is exposed. But you and I are agreed on the trinitarian belief here.

@Anne- Never noticed the “faith of the Son of God” option for translation. Will have to study that more. In 1985, that verse took away my fear of death and need to accomplish things to earn God’s favor. It is an important verse to get right.

This is a Trinitarian answer, and thus evaluates Jesus in his human nature in relation to God his Father, to whom he depends on in his creatureliness as one of us, since he is 100% human as well as 100% God.
I think the confusion is rooted in 3 aspects of what Christians often label as "faith":

The tag definition represents one ("Faith: Belief, trust, and loyalty towards God, Jesus, and the Christian religion."  This is trust in God's character.
The other is in relation to Knowledge, faith as light for us to know God; grace is the enablement for our reason to reach farther than what reason alone can know of God's existence.  But by faith we know God's love for us, etc., and that Christ is God's loving gift for us to be saved by.  This is the sense of faith implied by 1 Cor 13:1-13 when Paul said the prophecy is knowledge that will end when we see God, to help us know God in this life, which is "through a glass darkly" (v. 12, KJV).
The third is our faith in God's gracious sustaining of us as creature.   This faith is a combination of #1 and #2:

the knowledge of our creatureliness makes us humble in the face of our true situation (from dust we came from dust we will return)
the trust like Job that God knows every single one of our hair and he would not let one drop unless He allows it.  This is the trust Jesus talks about of not worrying what to eat, wear, etc.



Now that we have distinguished the 3 different senses of "faith", we can apply this to Jesus:

Even in his human nature, Jesus knows who he is (via Beatific vision): He is God the Word incarnate, so he doesn't see his Father "in faith" the way we do, i.e. through the glass darkly.  He is given the fullness of grace and truth (John 1:14), so he doesn't need faith in this sense.

But Jesus, purposefully decided to operate in a human fashion in following God's will day by day (John 5:19), praying every day; this is an expression of trust to daily align his own human will to the divine will.  So in living a life fully obedient to God's will, in this sense he has faith, and becomes our model.  Many verses imply this, such as he thanking the Father for his miracles, for protecting the disciples, etc.
By the way, his way of life was a perfect fulfillment of the Mosaic covenant as well in that he did all according to the spirit of the Law: love God and neighbors with all his heart, along with the intensification of the law that he preached at the Sermon on the Mount.  I'm sure he also went to the temple to worship God and made the necessary sacrifices (although not explicitly mentioned in the Bible). Finally, on this earth, there was a perfect Israelite who trusted God completely.

Most importantly, Jesus in his human nature is still a creature like us, so in fulfilling his mission to give up his life for us, he needs God to give him strength, perseverance, obedience, and the relinquishing of his human instinct for self-preservation and for naturally just goals of human life (such as procreation, food, shelter, etc).  His creatureliness is most evident in Gethsemane where he was naturally fearful and in need of divine comfort.  Although he knows God and loves God perfectly, it is still hard.  In a sense, he needs faith that God will sustain him as creature, that not one hair will fall off without God's permission even though he was about to be tortured and killed.


For a good discussion about this, hear the Tough Christology Questions interview on the relationship between Christ's divine and human knowledge (25:28), Christ's beatific vision and "self-awareness" (31:47) (better media player for this episode here).

Faith can only justify the ungodly and if faith was a merit the
God would be ‘justifying goodness’  that we have and not godlessness. ‘However, to the one who does not work but trusts God who justifies the ungodly, their faith is credited as righteousness. ‘(Romans 4:5). Now one, when an ‘enemy to God’ which must mean without virtue, needs to have faith ‘before’ being credited with righteousness as a result. When we are credited with righteousness we are absolutely ungodly,  therefore faith can’t be a virtue.
There are different kinds of faith. When we have faith we do so as sinners with a faith that has no virtue or merit in it. We have faith that Christ’s death on our behalf is able to pay for the punishment of our sin and that his obedience to the Law imputed to us is able to satisfy all the positive requirements of God’s Law.  Our faith is justifying faith because through it we obtain undeserved forgiveness and legal recognition of moral perfection while we are deplorable sinners without any virtue.
Christ as a man was sinless and had no need of a justifying faith to save him like we do.  He did have trust and have reliance upon the Father and this is a different kind of faith, a virtuous faith. We can’t experience a virtuous faith until after we have been reconciled through our faith in the gospel while sinners without any merit.  In addition any virtuous kind of trust after conversion still depends on our continued reliance on a saving faith as its source, for we can only receive Christ as a sinner and he never died for any righteous or healthy.  The origin of all our virtue is this selfish justifying faith from our unholy sickness and need. The origin of all of Christ’s virtues was his own divine nature and his natural obedience to the Father without sin. These are totally different subjects. His trust in God was only one part of what we needed for salvation. His death was centrally important as sin must not go unpunished.  It is absolutely impossible, scripturally and logically that our justifying faith can be anything like a virtuous faith because we first had this faith when God’s enemies. As sinners and enemies we are to believe in order to be reconciled. There can be no virtue until after being reconciled and given His Spirit to dwell in us.
In conclusion, obviously these are two vastly different kinds of faith. One born from guilt and need, the other born from innocence and infinite resources. If faith had merit undeserved favor would be sneakily, by the Devil’s craft, turned into something deserved.

The faith of the justified is seen by God as valuable. For therein is the Righteousness of God believed as having been demonstrated at Golgotha. Seeing such a faith, God justifies the one whose faith it is. For God sees His Own Righteousness in the faith. Abraham believed God and there was evaluated to him unto righteousness.

@Nigel - I have absolutely no faith in faith.

That is an interesting way to look at it.

@Mike It is the content of the faith that is valuable - the Righteousness of God.

@NigelJ - yes I can agree with that.

@Mike This is what is often missed in the matter of 'justification by faith'. It is an important point in my own judgment.

I think this is a good explanation.

This is one of many dilemmas caused by the Trinity doctrine, and other Christologies that suppose that Jesus is God proper himself. What meaning is there in asserting that Jesus was fully man if in fact he did not have to have faith in God (being God) nor again was he capable of being tempted or sinning (since God cannot be tempted and does not sin)? Clearly one who is incapable of falling cannot truly be said to have experienced and overcome all the trials and tribulations common to man.
Indeed, the Trinity doctrine basically turns the temptation of Christ by the devil into a farce. Consider when the devil tempted Christ by offering him the world if he but bow down. How could that be a temptation to God himself, who is the creator and ruler of all already?
On the other hand, consider for a moment that Jesus is not God Almighty. Jesus is promised that he will be exalted overall - given power and authority over all creation - but he does not ascend to this position, at the right hand of God, until after the crucifixion and ascension. Now we can see where the temptation is: the devil is offering him something very similar to what God will reward him with, but without having to sacrifice himself! And, of course, we know that facing the crucifixion was a tremendous stress on the Lord. He stayed up all night praying that God might take this cup from him if possible. When he was being taken to be crucified at Golgotha, he literally sweat blood (a rare medical condition induced by great levels of stress).
With that very human sense of self-preservation in mind that Jesus was having to fight against to fulfill God's will, the devil's offer here takes on a whole new depth of meaning. But it is only meaningful if Jesus is not God Almighty. If Jesus is God Almighty then this temptation is complete non-sense.
To more directly answer your question: I'm not aware of any sect that posits that it is Jesus' faith which is salvific over and against his fulfillment of the Law and the Prophets or his perfect obedience to God's will, etc. Certainly he had faith, and this was important. For example: when the disciples could not cast out a demon, Christ did it instead. He explained to them that it could only be done through faith.
I don't belong to a sect myself at this point in my life, but I have come to describe my views as post-orthodox.

Your reasoning is a sound one if you reject the Trinity and Dual nature of Christ.  I cannot agree with that reasoning of course. But I thank you for actually answering the primary question, I was unaware of any such sects either.

@Wyrsa it's a complicated topic, but one worth investing your time to investigate :) The Lord promises us that those who ask shall receive, those who seek shall find, and that if you knock the door will be opened. So keep at it! And consider that there is plenty of precedence in the OT for those other than God Almighty being referred to as if God - like the angel in the burning bush (Exodus 3) and Moses (Exodus 7). Indeed, Jesus is the one prophesied to be like Moses.

I have investigated much, but I have strived to listen (or in this case read) to those who were better examples and understood better than I do. (Sirach 8:8) In so doing, I've decided that I will not reject the Eucumenical councils or their statements of Faith. I have investigated many of the other interpretations, to better understand.

@Wyrsa I agree with starting by trying to understand a given tradition. I grew up a Trinitarian myself. I spent the most time with the Church of the Nazarene growing up, where my dad also trained to be a priest. When I went to college, I bought the Ante-Nicene Fathers series and spent several years just reading through the writings of the early church fathers. I told myself that despite my reservations about the Trinity, if (as everyone asserted), I found that the early church was Trinitarian then I would accept that I was in error. Of course, the early church wasn't (like Justin Martyr).

@Wyrsa Ultimately all those who came before us were fallible men, no different than ourselves. So learn from them - but also be ready to acknowledge where they fall short and be willing to push beyond that for your own spiritual growth. The Church Fathers were hardly in agreement with eachother - and it was only through fierce debate and political force and death threats that the Roman Empire ever came to standardize anything about the faith. And outside of the Roman Empire, differing opinions contrary to the councils continued until conquered. Such use of force to force compliance is not holy

To be fair, you do understand then that the original church only spoke up specifically against heresies. The Trinity understanding was first put into words, to soundly resist heresies that would destroy the faith. For example the Gnostics, there is no "secret knowledge" and "material is not evil" :) It makes it hard to find pre-nicene teaching against a heresy that didn't really exist yet.

@Wyrsa the Apologists like Justin Martyr were primarily addressing heresies - but in doing so they put forth their own opinions on what was the correct / orthodox interpretation - which was a combination of their own individual thoughts and the collective wisdom passed down to them at that point in time. By studying the writings of the Church Fathers, you get a glimpse into the evolution of theological thought over the course of time. You can further divide this in to regional variants - particularly before the ecumenical councils.

@Wyrsa If you honestly study the writings of the early church, you will find that they held Jesus to be distinct from God Almighty. Justin calls him a second, lesser god. Even those who assert that he is the same God, like Tertullian, do so by virtue of the substance of which he is begot. Tertullian still maintained that there was a time when God was not the Father, a time when the Son did not exist. The idea that Jesus was eternally begotten was a relatively late idea - one which I believe originated with Origen in the 3rd century.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Frame Challenge: It's all in the definition
I am not aware of any Christian traditions that hold that view, the way you understood it.
But. I think this is an issue of verbal clarity,* not theology. A combination of sloppy wording and fuzzy definitions on the part of the commenter.**
Every Christian denomination I know would agree that Jesus was faithful unto death. That is to say, faith in the sense of loyalty, which is indeed in the definition you reference. (They would likewise agree our salvation wasn't won only by his Passion- anyone can suffer and die- but all would say the Passion was necessary.)
*So perhaps you could ask the author of that comment themselves specifically what they mean. If they indeed mean what you thought they meant, ask what their denomination is and report back- we'll both learn something new :)
**To be fair, English has a particularly nasty issue of words changing meanings over time, and many English-speaking denominations frequently intermix older and modern meanings of common words. This statement might be perfectly clear to members of the commenter's local church.

*So perhaps you could ask the author of that comment themselves specifically what they mean. If they indeed mean what you thought they meant, ask what their denomination is and report back- we'll both learn something new :)

**To be fair, English has a particularly nasty issue of words changing meanings over time, and many English-speaking denominations frequently intermix older and modern meanings of common words. This statement might be perfectly clear to members of the commenter's local church.

This specific commenter doesn't usually engage in chats or things. And I thought the question was unique and deserved a good answer here on the site in general. I don't understand why you used asterisks instead of just putting those thoughts up in the main body of the answer?

"Commenter doesn't engage..." -> Gotcha

"Asterisks in the comments" -> Yeah, that was kind of a weird thing for me to do, wasn't it? I don't remember why. Will copy them up to the body as an edit

"Question unique, deserves an answer" -> I don't disagree, and I apologize if my answer sounded dismissive. A "frame challenge" is common language on other SEs that probably doesn't translate well here. It's a shorthand flag that maybe we should examine a premise more than give a direct answer. But my direct answer is indeed stated up front - I don't know of any denominations that hold that view when "faith" means "belief," and I believe an alternative definition (as also asked in your question) is warranted for that statement to be understood well

No worries, I'm not saying your answer was bad. The asterisks in the comments, I think I know why... because the text box likes to use them as formatting for italics and bold text.  I've actually started to use ° and ~instead of * for that purpose.

This is a Trinitarian dilemma. Prayer and faith are inseparably connected - without faith, one would not pray!
The French Theologian Jacques Guillet (he wrote a book called "The Consciousness of Jesus" from which I will put a few quotes in here) said:

HOW could Jesus have had faith? He is God; he knows and sees
everything without having to turn to anybody else. Now faith consists
precisely in leaning on another and in admitting that which is not
seen; that Jesus-God could have had faith, therefore, is excluded.

The question of Jesus' faith really is an enigma for Catholic, Protestant, and Orthodox theologians who believe in the Trinity as "the central mystery of Christian faith and life." Not all deny Jesus' faith, however.
Jacques Guillet affirms that "it is impossible not to recognize that Jesus had faith," though Guillet admits that, in the light of Trinity doctrine, it is a "paradox."
Faith consists in believing in another, not in believing in oneself. In modern language, if you tell someone to "believe in himself", it usually means that that person does NOT believe in their own capabilities. I don't think that Jesus, if he were God Almighty, would have such a lack of self-awareness, irrespective of having 2 distinct wills in the hypostatic union.
Jesus, himself, makes the connection between faith and prayer. Consider these scriptures:

Matthew 21:21-22: And Jesus answered and said to them, "Truly I
say to you, if you have faith, and do not doubt, you shall not only do
what was done to the fig tree, but even if you say to this mountain,
‘Be taken up and cast into the sea,’ it shall happen. (22) And all
things you ask in prayer, believing, you will receive." (Clear
statement about faith / prayer)


Mark 11:20-25: As they were passing by in the morning, they saw
the fig tree withered from the roots up. (21) Being reminded, Peter
said to Him, "Rabbi, look, the fig tree which You cursed has
withered." (22) And Jesus answered saying to them, "Have faith in God.
(23) "Truly I say to you, whoever says to this mountain, 'Be taken up
and cast into the sea,' and does not doubt in his heart, but believes
that what he says is going to happen, it will be granted him. (24)
"Therefore I say to you, all things for which you pray and ask,
believe that you have received them, and they will be granted you.
(25) "Whenever you stand praying, forgive, if you have anything
against anyone, so that your Father who is in heaven will also forgive
you your transgressions. (Clear statement about faith / prayer)

Jesus was a man of prayer. He prayed on every occasion​—when he was baptized (Luke 3:21); the whole night before choosing his 12 apostles (Luke 6:12, 13); and before his miraculous transfiguration on the mountain, while with the apostles Peter, John, and James. (Luke 9:28, 29) He was praying when one of the disciples asked him: “Teach us how to pray,” so he taught them the Lord’s Prayer (the “Our Father”). (Luke 11:1-4; Matthew 6:9-13) He prayed alone and at length early in the morning (Mark 1:35-39); toward evening, on a mountain, after dismissing his disciples (Mark 6:45, 46); together with his disciples and for his disciples. (Luke 22:32; John 17:1-26) Prayer was an important part of Jesus' life.
If Jesus did not have faith, why did he pray to God? Whom did the man Jesus invoke? Was he unaware that he was God as well? On whose will did Jesus switch between his natures? Or were they working simultaneously? And if he was God and knew it, why did he pray at all? Couldn't he just have transmitted thoughts between his natures/wills/minds?
Jesus' prayers on the last day of his earthly life give us an even deeper insight into his firm faith in his heavenly Father whom Jesus declared to be "the only true God" (John 17:3). Manifesting hope and confident expectation, he requested: "So now you, Father, glorify me alongside yourself with the glory that I had alongside you before the world was."​ — John 17:5.
Knowing that his most difficult trials and his death were imminent, the night he was in the garden of Gethsemane on the Mount of Olives, "he started to be grieved and to be sorely troubled," and he said: "My soul is deeply grieved, even to death." (Matthew 26:36-38) Then he knelt and prayed: "Father, if you wish, remove this cup from me. Nevertheless, let, not my will, but yours take place." Then "an angel from heaven appeared to him and strengthened him." God listened to his prayer. Because of the intensity of his emotions and the severity of the trial, "his sweat became as drops of blood falling to the ground."​ — Luke 22:42-44.
What do Jesus' sufferings, his need to be strengthened, and his supplications indicate? Jacques Guillet wrote:

One thing is certain, Jesus prayed, and prayer is an essential aspect
of his life and of his actions. He prayed as men pray, and he prayed
in behalf of men. Now, men’s prayers are inconceivable without faith.
Would Jesus’ prayers be conceivable without faith?

Shortly before his death, Jesus cried out with a loud voice, quoting a psalm of David. Then, in faith, with a loud voice, he cried out a final supplication: "Father, into your hands I entrust my spirit." (Luke 23:46; Matthew 27:46) One Italian interdenominational translation, Parola del Signore, says that Jesus 'entrusted his life' to the Father.
Jacques Guillet comments:

Showing us the Christ crucified, crying out to his Father through the
psalms of Israel, the Gospel writers convince us that that cry, the
cry of the only-begotten Son, a cry of complete anguish, a cry of
total confidence, is a cry of faith, the cry of a death in faith.

Faced with this clear and dramatic evidence of faith, some theologians try to make a distinction between "faith" and "confidence." Such a distinction, however, is not based on the Scriptures.
But exactly what do the severe trials he endured reveal about Jesus' faith?
Jesus, the "Perfecter," Perfected

Hebrews 2:10: "It was fitting for the one for whose sake all things
are and through whom all things are, in bringing many sons to glory,
to make the Chief Agent of their salvation perfect through
sufferings."


Hebrews 2:17, 18: "He was obliged to become like his 'brothers' in all
respects, that he might become a merciful and faithful high priest in
things pertaining to God, in order to offer propitiatory sacrifice for
the sins of the people. For in that he himself has suffered when being
put to the test, he is able to come to the aid of those who are being
put to the test."


Hebrews 3:2: "He was faithful to the One that made him such, as Moses was also in all the house of that One."


Hebrews 4:15: "We have as high priest, not one who cannot sympathize with our weaknesses, but one who has been tested in all
respects like ourselves, but without sin."


Hebrews 5:7-9: "In the days of his flesh Christ offered up
supplications and also petitions to the One who was able to save him
out of death, with strong outcries and tears, and he was favorably
heard for his godly fear. Although he was a Son, he learned obedience
from the things he suffered; and after he had been made perfect he
became responsible for everlasting salvation."

Jesus was perfected by his sufferings and his obedience. Though already a perfect man, his experiences made him perfect and complete in all things, even in faith, in order for him to become fully qualified as High Priest for the salvation of true Christians. He supplicated his Father "with strong outcries and tears," he was "faithful" to God, and he had "godly fear." (Hebrews 3:1, 2; 5:7-9)
He was "tested in all respects" exactly "like ourselves," says Hebrews 4:15, that is, like any faithful Christian whose faith undergoes "various trials." (James 1:2, 3) Is it reasonable to believe that Jesus could be put to the test "like" his followers without being tested in his faith as they are?
Supplications, obedience, suffering, trials, faithfulness, and godly fear attest to the complete faith of Jesus. They indicate that he became the "Perfecter of our faith" only after being made perfect in his own faith. 1 John 5:5.
Jesus, the Model of Faith to Imitate
Jesus had to fight the fight of the faith down to the end in order to maintain loyalty to his Father and to 'conquer the world.' (John 16:33) Without faith, it is impossible to achieve such a victory. (Hebrews 11:6; 1 John 5:4) On account of that victorious faith, he was an example to his faithful followers. He certainly had faith in the true God.

This response was taken/inspired from the following article in The Watchtower - Oct 15th, 1994 with a few changes by me.
